# How to make the post summary taller?

Tags: posts, homepage

right now our posts on the landing page are only showing 2 lines of the content. How can I get the posts to show 5 lines of the content each?

Answer (score 2):

You can either manually enter content into `the_excerpt` section or use this code in your `functions.php` file in your theme

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
return 200;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Change the number 200 to the number of **characters** you want until it's the number of lines you're looking for.